# android: ScrollView cuts off the top

Tags: android, scrollview

So I have a layout with a `ScrollView`. When I test my code, the `ViewPager`-heigth jumps from a reasonable value (1845) to very small (so fast the eye can't see). If I switch the `layout_height` of the `ViewPager` to `wrap_content` the height jumps to 0.

Aditionally, when the `ViewPager` has a heigth > 0, the top half of it is outside the Screen and only the bottom half is visible.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDeadBackground"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_pics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.finder.ViewPagerIndicator.LinePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            app:strokeWidth="2dp"
            app:unselectedColor="#88888888"
            app:selectedColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
...
```

If I set the height to a fixed value (either programatically or in the xml) the problem persists, that only the top half of the ViewPager is seen. Even the preview Window says its only half on the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the weird offset thing (that the `ViewPager` starts obove the screen), I had to remove the `android:layout_gravity="center"` from the `Linearlayout`. No idea why, if someone explains that to me, that would be dope. Probably has soemthing to do, that I used `android:layout_gravity="center"` twice in the `Linearlayout` and in the `CardView`.

Then I still ahd to set the height of the `ViewPager` programatically, so that the height isn't 0. No idea why either, doesn't matter if I changed `match_parent` to `wrap_content` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the `CardView` height and `ViewPager` height both on `match_parent`, which will cause an issue in visibitily , try to set a fixed size to height for both of them !

Comment: If I set the height to a fixed value (either programatically or in the xml) the problem persists, that only the top half of the `ViewPager` is seen. have a look at my edit.