# the empty space below notificationbar is overlapping my items?

Tags: android

[image]

I've just created a new project and added a scrollview with an linearlayout, containing 5 cardviews and this happened.
I've removed the toolbar in resources/style so it's not that.

fyi: it is at the top of the scroll so there is no space to go up.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/note1"/>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/note2"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/note3"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/note4"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/note5"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/floating_button"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seemed like a weird bug, after I removed `layout_gravity` attribute, it was fixed, thanks to this topic:

[android: ScrollView cuts off the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911344/android-scrollview-cuts-off-the-top)

Answer (score 0):

You should use recyclerview for these type of screens